# Ler determinadas colunas de arquivo xls em Python com XLRD

Tags: python, microsoft-excel, xls

sou principiante na linguagem e estou tentando exibir o conteúdo de uma planilha eletrônica no front end com Python. Com esse código estou exibindo o resultado das colunas nome, sobrenome, cidade e nota, constantes na planilha, e nessa ordem.

```
def exibir(request):      
    workbook = xlrd.open_workbook("teste.xlsx", encoding_override="cp1252")
    worksheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)
    dados = []
    
    for row_num in range(worksheet.nrows):
        if row_num == 0:
            continue
        row = worksheet.row_values(row_num)
        usuario = Usuario(row[0], row[1], row[2], float(row[3]))
        dados.append(usuario)
    return render(request, 'lista.html', {'lista': dados})
```

Agora eu quero fazer com que eu receba o arquivo e exiba o resultado de 3 colunas específicas da planilha, selecionadas pelo nome da coluna (nome, cidade e email). Não posso selecionar pelo índice porque cada planilha pode variar a quantidade de colunas, já os nomes não variam. Alguém pode me ajudar?

Answer (score -1):

Opa,

Acredito que você esteja procurando pelo método `col_values`. Veja a [documentação](https://xlrd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html).

> col_values(colx, start_rowx=0, end_rowx=None)

*Returns a slice of the values of the cells in the given column.*

Para o seu caso, seria algo como:

```
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook("teste.xlsx", encoding_override="cp1252")
worksheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)
columnValues = sheet.col_values(columnIndex)  # columnIndex é o índice da coluna. Começando em 0 para a coluna A.
```

Caso você tenha uma linha de cabeçalho, pode fazer algo como:

```
columnValues = sheet.col_values(columnIndex, 1)
```

Espero que ajude.